# Load undefined images from folders

Tags: c#, windows, forms, png, image-gallery

I saw many similar threads, but nothing that could help me solving my problem. I'm new to c# and I want to load 3 images into 3 picture boxes from 3 different folders on a form and print them later. The images are created through screenshots by a third party application and saved in those folders. 
Nevertheless I can't define their names which is making problems with the file path, I think... 
Instead of creating a SystemWatchFolder, I saw someone using: 
`open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png"`
Is that working in general or do I need a watch folder?

I tried to combine codes from similar projects and ended up with the one below (btw sorry for posting the whole code). 
I also tried to change the path to: (@"C:....)
same error message.

I really need and appreciate your help, comments, thoughts etc.

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\");
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";

    pictureBox1.Image = bmp;

}
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\");
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";

    pictureBox2.Image = bmp;

}

private void PictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot3\\");
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";

    pictureBox3.Image = bmp;

}
private void PictureBox3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

The images in the boxes are not shown and I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Parameter is not valid.'

for this line:
`Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot1\\");`

Comment: First find image file by `OpenFileDialog`. Then create `Bitmap` with path to image in constructor

Comment: Why `Form1_Load` works with `pictureBox1` as it PictureBox1_Click? Wrong name or you try to open file dialog not after click and on Form Load too?

Comment: @Lemm thanks a lot for your help and those different options. I just realised that i'll have to try it without openFileDialog, since i'm looking to load the image without interactions

Comment: @Lemm The problem is that the image is not existing at the moment. "Snapshot 2" is the folder where the image is saved after it will be taken. And it should then be shown, without browsing to the direction

Comment: You should periodically  check is picture is present in folder and if it is saved load it. Problem is you need to know file name before file is created or be sure that this folder will contain only those files that you need. Read about Time to implement this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: @Lemm That's exactly what i need, but sounds like a watch folder and a lot of work... But i can't define the file name, because it is done automatically through a snapshot programm where the images come from. BUT the folder "Snapshot2" will always just contain one image, which is always the one that should be shown. Is this possible in a simple way?

Comment: Just using timer call DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method. Sort those files by their date created and then load first(n) files to you picture box. Where N is number of picture boxes without Image inside. After all picture boxes are filled with your pictures stop the timer. Note that if old pictures will be in those folder on program start your picture boxes will be filled with old ones not the new ones, in that case you will need to delete all files from folder at program start. More about DirectoryInfo.GetFiles method you can read here DirectoryInfo.GetFiles

Comment: @Lemm thanks again for your help. I'll try that. System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath) might also suit my needs. I'll just have to try what is working best for me

Comment: Yeah it will be much better that GetFiles. Just specify path to directory and search pattern (*.png i'll guess be fine for files with png extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What are you doing wrong

At first your `Bitmap` should take path to your picture. So it must be initialized at the end after user selects picture in `OpenFileDialog`. Also, you never opened your `OpenFileDialog`.

So all your methods should look look this:

```
private void PictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

### Better way to do this

You really don't need to create three similar methods that doing the same thing.
You can create only one and use it in all picture boxes:

```
private void PictureBox_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
    open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
        PictureBox targetPictureBox = e.Source as PictureBox;
        targetPictureBox.Image = bmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the following code:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\");
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";

pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

there are two problems:

#### Problem 1

In the line:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\");
```

You are loading a `Bitmap` image from a file. The path:

```
"C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\"
```

is incorrect because it cant end with a `\\`.
It should end with `Snapshot2` or `Snapshot2.png` depending on the name of the file.

#### Problem 2

In the lines:

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";
```

You are initializing an `OpenFileDialog` but not using it. You can get the file name by using a file dialogue or hard-code the file name as you did in the first line, but you are mixing theme up.

#### Option 1: Hard-coding the file name

This should work, assuming the file name is `Snapshot2.png`:

```
Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2.png");
pictureBox2.Image = bmp;
```

#### Option 2: Using a file dialogue

```
OpenFileDialog open = new OpenFileDialog();
open.Filter = "Image Files (*.png)|*.png";
if (open.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    pictureBox2.Image = new Bitmap(open.FileName);
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer and those options. I prefer the option 1, since i want this happen without a file dialog or user interaction. Therefore i need to know, if i need to make changes to the form itself? Because somehow it's still not working for me... and is there any code i need to add for Option 1 to work?

Comment: The problem is, that the image is not existing. That's why i tried to get to the folder and just show the created image. "Snapshot 2" is the folder, not the image.

Comment: You need the full path to the image. If the image name is `img.png` and it is the folder path `C:\Users\Public\1-2d27a482-b755\Files\Snapshots\Snapshot2` than the full path is `C:\Users\Public\1-2d27a482-b755\Files\Snapshots\Snapshot2\img.png` and in your code you need to write:  `Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap("C:\\Users\\Public\\1-2d27a482-b755\\Files\\Snapshots\\Snapshot2\\img.png");`

Comment: thanks for the quick response. So is there no way to get this done when i don't know the image name? The name is set automatically/random through a snapshot program and i can't change that. That's why i don't know it before it is taken... What if the folder "Snaphot2" just contains this created image? Is there a way to show the content of the folder "Snapshot2" then?

Comment: Use `System.IO.Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath)` to get all files in a folder path